# True and False. Linear Algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, orthogonality, vector-space-isomorphism

[image: True and False]

My solutions are as follows

1: True
2: False
3: False
4: True
5: True

Are these solutions reasonable? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said I'm voting to close this question  because you show no work of your own. To get  help rather than downvotes or votes to close please edit the question to show us your work in each case. Indicate the places where you are unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is true, the rest of your solutions is correct.

As for the second one: similarity of $A$ and $B$ means that for some invertible $S$ we have $B= SAS^{-1}$. (Note that $A$ and $B$ have the same type and they are square matrices as they are invertible, so all three of the matrices $A,B,S$ are $n\times n$ for some $n$.)

Take the inverse of both sides (makes sense, as the product of invertible matrices is invertible): $B^{-1}= SA^{-1}S^{-1}$, so $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are also similar. In fact, you can conjugate by the same matrix that witnesses the similarity of $A$ and $B$.